# LogicException: The selected node does not have a form ancestor

Tags: forms, form-submit, sonata-admin, domcrawler, ancestor

I'm trying to submit a sonata form using crawler but i noticed that sonata moved the submit button outside the form so when i try to submit i have this error: "LogicException: The selected node does not have a form ancestor.".
Does anybody know when and where Sonata move the button outiside the form? And does anybody know how to solve the problem and submit the form with crawler?
Thank you

I tried to debug the submit method but it goes in exception without show me when it moves out the buttom from the form.